# Plot factor levels in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the iris data, previously changed the species factor from "setosa" "versicolor" and "virginica" to "s", "c" and "v". if I code this:
`plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length, col = iris$Species)`
The data are point which can change for example, to a square:
`plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length, col = iris$Species, pch = 15)`
but, how I could show the species factor like this
graph?

[image: graph]

Comment: Try with `pch = c("S", "C", "V")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we use the factor as an index to labels:

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length, col = as.numeric(iris$Species)+1,
  pch = c("s", "c", "v")[as.numeric(iris$Species)])
```

---

Resulting plot:

[image: 2D iris data subset plotted with letters as symbols]

Comment: Perfect, it's just what I needed, Thanks!